# Filtering multiple value in angularjs (from input part)

Tags: angularjs

From what i have learn from angular js filter API in the official documentation, I have seen something like this.

```html
<label>Any: <input ng-model="search.$"></label> <br>
<label>Name only <input ng-model="search.name"></label><br>
<label>Phone only <input ng-model="search.phone"></label><br>
<label>Address only <input ng-model="search.address"></label><br>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:search>
      {{contact.name}}, {{contact.phone}}...
  </li>
</ul>
```

now, suppose i would like to add a new input where user can only search for Name and Phone only and retain the previous input search, what should I do. Means after the implementation i would have five search input where user can search by any, name only, phone only, address only or name or phone. The five search input must be visible and available to user and cannot be disabled.

Kindly ignore whether it is logical to do it this way and assume that it is  a definite requirement.

I would expect something like this but it won't work

```html
<label>Any: <input ng-model="search.$"></label> <br>
    <label>Name only <input ng-model="search.name"></label><br>
    <label>Phone only <input ng-model="search.phone"></label><br>
    <label>Address only <input ng-model="search.address"></label><br>
    <label>Name or phone only <input ng-model="search.name || search.phone"></label><br>

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:search>
          {{contact.name}}, {{contact.phone}}...
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your filter is on search, you can create a new property of search for the name or phone input field I guess? So you could just do:

```
<label>Name or phone only <input ng-model="search.nameOrPhone"></label>
```

Or does it HAVE to be search.name / search.phone?
It's pretty devious to achieve the assigning to either search.name / search.phone based on the input, but it can be done. You could create a ng-change function I guess, which checks the input with reg-ex, then either assigns search.name or search.phone.